# Compare and Add data from one worksheet to another in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, worksheet, multiple-entries

How can I add rows of data from one worksheet to another after comparing it with each other for existing entries?
I have tried doing it, but the only problem is that there are duplicate entries which are being added to it.

```html
For Each Cell1 In Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Worksheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        
        For Each Cell3 In Worksheets(3).Range("A1", Worksheets(3).Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    
            If Not Cell1 = Cell3 Then
                Dim LastRow3 As Long
                LastRow3 = Worksheets(3).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
                Worksheets(3).Range("A1:C1").Rows(LastRow3).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C1").Rows(Cell1.Row).Value
                
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
    
        Next Cell3

Next Cell1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Find() is easier to manage than using a nested loop:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Range, f As Range
    Dim ws1, ws3

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws3 = Worksheets(3)

    For Each c In ws1.Range(ws1.Range("A1"), ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells

        Set f = ws3.Range(ws3.Range("A1"), _
                           ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find( _
                                      What:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If f Is Nothing Then
            ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                                                        c.Resize(1, 3).Value
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Is There any site or book, that I can refer for working on VBA Excel??? I have just started.

Comment: I like John Walkenbach's "Power Progamming" books